# Condition in .rules file in prometheus-alertmanager

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to use conditions in snmp.rules file that is notify us via Slack configs. Basically we want to use a condition to suppress node down alert if there is already a site down.

Example: A site has 4 nodes. I have configured 4 rules since they are of different types like Router, Wireless, Switches and going to different channels. But there is one more rule for Site down. We do not want to send notification for node downs alerts when the complete site is down.

Is it feasible in `Prometheus Alertmanager` to use something in the expression?

```
expr: probe_success{job="snmp_icmp", instance="cis004a01"} == 0

expr: probe_success{job="snmp_icmp", site_code="004"} == 0
```

Inhibit Rules says - Apply Inhibition if the alertname is the same. In my case, alertnames would be different. Right? But I would still give a shot. Also, I tried the expression as well, it is giving all the alerts. I have two sites, wherein 1 site has only 1 router down and Site 2 has all the nodes down. When I am running the given expression, it is giving all the node down alerts. It should give only Site 1 - Node 1 down alert. Site 2 - All Nodes should get suppressed

Comment: avg(probe_success{job="snmp_icmp", site_code="004"}) == 0

Comment: "Apply Inhibition if the alertname is the same." is a comment for example provided by Prometheus. That comment explains exact configuration provided in an example, and has nothing to do with current situation.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways: inhibit_rules in alertmanager configuration, or use of expression filtering out this case.

### inhibit_rule

Inhibition rules allow to mute a set of alerts given that another alert is firing.

Example of configuration:

```yaml
inhibit_rules:
  - source_matchers: [alertname="SiteDown"]
    target_matchers: [alertname=~"(Router|Wireless|Switches)Down"]
    # CAUTION:
    #   If all label names listed in `equal` are missing
    #   from both the source and target alerts,
    #   the inhibition rule will apply!
    equal: []
```

This will prevent firing of alerts with names matching regex if alert `SiteDown` has fired already.

More examples of configurations [here](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/main/doc/examples/simple.yml).

### expression

You can use logical operator to filter out case where your site is down.

Example for your case:

```
probe_success{job="snmp_icmp", site_code="004"} == 0 and on() probe_success{job="snmp_icmp", site_code="004"} == 1
```

Here alert will be fired if any of `probe_success{job="snmp_icmp", site_code="004"}` returns 0, but exists at least one for the same selector, that returns 1.

It's a bit of a clever simplification of you "site down" rule. If you want straight substitution it would be:

```
probe_success{job="snmp_icmp", site_code="004"} == 0
  unless on() avg(probe_success{job="snmp_icmp", site_code="004"}) == 0
```

Comment: @Sagar_Bhutani, oops sorry, copied it from sample. Here alertnames will be different as stated in matchers.

Comment: Inhibit Rules says - Apply Inhibition if the alertname is the same. In my case, alertnames would be different. Right? But I would still give a shot.

Also, I tried the expression as well, it is giving all the alerts. I have two sites, wherein 1 site has only 1 router down and Site 2 has all the nodes down. When I am running the given expression, it is giving all the node down alerts. It should give only Site 1 - Node 1 down alert. Site 2 - All Nodes should get suppressed

Comment: @Sagar_Bhutani all that information should be in question, not comments. For two sites you need to adjust `equal`, for inhibition, and `on` clause for expressions.