# Prometheus alerting on same rule with different labels

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

please, consider this:

lets say I have this rule:

```yaml
- alert: EndpointIsDown
  expr:
    probe_success == 0
  for: 7m
  labels:
    severity: critical
  annotations:
    summary: "{{ $labels.instance }} is Down"
    description: "{{ $labels.instance }} is down for > 5m"
```

it is matching all the probes I've defined for any endpoints.

now lets say I want to treat some endpoints different(different `for` duration, alert `annotations` and ...). like:

```yaml
- alert: SpecificEpIsDown
  expr:
    probe_success{label_a="this"} == 0
  for: 2m
  labels:
    severity: critical
  annotations:
    summary: "{{ $labels.instance }} is Down"
    description: "{{ $labels.instance }} is down for > 5m"
    newAnnot1: value1
    newAnnot2: value2
```

if I define both rules then I'll have two alerts for same problem. one is firing from first rule and one from second one.

The only thing I can think of is to change them to something like this:
rule 1: probe_success{application!="this"} == 0

rule 2: probe_success{application="this"} == 0

but lets say I have multiple cases like these, each time I add something I have to edit rule 1 and add new regex to exclude rule 2 label(and I have multiple metrics like this, its not just this one). I think it will become a mess pretty soon.

Could You please help me how to handle this? I'm not exprienced with alerting/monitoring, please if I'm doing it wrong let me know what are the alternative ways or how should I do it?

```yaml
- alert: SpecificEpIsDown
  expr:
    probe_success{label_a="this"} == 0
  for: 2m
  labels:
    severity: critical
  annotations:
    summary: "{{ $labels.instance }} is Down"
    description: "{{ $labels.instance }} is down for > 5m"
    newAnnot1: value1
    newAnnot2: value2
```

Comment: You have two general ways: use inhibition rules to stop general alert if specific one is already fired, or expression that will consider all this. Both has their advantages and disadvantages, but I would recommend inhibition. Here is [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76877638/)